# uninitialized constant RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I use rspec-guard to run my tests continuously, but sometimes the tests fails because of:

```
Running: spec/requests/signup_spec.rb
FF

Failures:

  1) Signup does not email confirmation mail after signup
     Failure/Error: visit new_user_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `new_user_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x00000100ad5fd8>
     # ./spec/requests/signup_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Signup should email confirmation mail after signup
     Failure/Error: user = Factory.build(:user)
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Factory
     # ./spec/requests/signup_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Sometimes they work and sometimes they don't work.. I dont know why..

Can you help me?

**EDIT:**
I use following versions:

- ruby 1.9.2-p290
- rails 3.1.rc4
- rspec (2.6.0)
- rspec-rails (2.6.1)
- factory_girl (2.0.0.rc4)
- factory_girl_rails (1.1.rc1)

And as you can see, the routes arent working too: new_user_path not found...?

And this is my request spec:

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
describe "Signup" do
  it "does not email confirmation mail after signup" do
    visit new_user_path
    fill_in 'user_unconfirmed_email', :with => 'none@example.net'
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => ''
    fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', :with => ''
    click_button "Create User"
    current_path.should eq(user_path)
    page.should have_content("is too short")
    last_email.should be_nil
  end

  it "should email confirmation mail after signup" do
    user = Factory.build(:user)
    visit root_path
    fill_in 'user_unconfirmed_email', :with => user.unconfirmed_email
    fill_in 'user_password', :with => user.unconfirmed_email
    fill_in 'user_password_confirmation', :with => user.unconfirmed_email
    click_button "Create User"
    current_path.should eq(root_path)
    page.should have_content("You successfully signed up! An email with your activation link was sent to your mail address.")
    last_email.to.should include(user.unconfirmed_email)
    last_email.body.should include(user.email_confirmation_key)
    open_email(user.unconfirmed_email)
    click_first_link_in_email # email spec
    current_path.should eq(new_user_path)
    page.should have_content "Your email was successfully confirmed. You are now able to log in with it!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Argh... found the solution.. I forgot to include

```
require 'spec_helper.rb'
```

in my specs...

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same issue, but in my case, I forgot to restart spork.

Spork is a gem that greatly decreases test duration using rspec. Recommended!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but in my case I mistakenly had my spec under spec/models whereas it should have been under spec/requests.